# File Upload - Customise Browse window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I've got a bit tricky problem... I've got this file upload control which is only used for uploading profile images. When it is clicked it opens a Windows explorer Browse window. I would like this window to have the filter preselected on image files (.jpg, .png, etc.) and mine only has "All Files". This is what I'm talkin about:

[image: AllFiles]

I would also like to set a default location for the folder. Is there any way to set this Browse window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that if your browser supports HTML5 by adding the `accept` tag to your file input:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/jpg, image/gif" />
```

If your browser doesn't support HTML5 you are pretty much busted. Prefiltering file input dialogs in legacy browsers to a certain file type simply is not supported. You will have to use Flash or some equivalent client side scripting technology. You might take a look at some file upload controls such as [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), [BlueImp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which are abstracting much of this hassle for you.

Comment: well, i use devexpress... :D I can't find anything like that. I need to browse their documentation a bit more